# javascript how reference variable using php (basic)

Tags: php, html

Edit - This post identifies fundamental knowledge errors in the way PHP works.

If youre getting stuck like I was, check out the following and then read everypage linked to them...

php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php, php.net//manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
Thanks to Felix Kling for the links.

Original query -

So - not my website just helping out.

My understanding was  - use GET to obtain the HTML id and then define the variable using the if statement.

However - it seems that no matter what drop down is selected, it returns var2 as 5?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

PHP/Javascript

```
if ($_GET['example']="sample")
{
$var2= 5;  
}
else
{
$var2= 0; 
}
```

html

```
  <select name="example" id="example" >
          <option value="sample">sample</option>
          <option value="sample2">sample2</option>
  </select>
      </label></td>
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what is your problem with the code. Care to explain in more detail?

Comment: $_GET['example']=="sample". php comaprison operator is "==", not "="

Comment: Are you `POST`ing the form? or do you have `GET`? Can we see your complete form code?

Comment: Im using var2 to subtract from a different variable (var1). When running the code, it either always subtracts 5 (if using =) or wont wont subrtacrt at all (if using ==). Just stuck on where im going wrong here.

Comment: Don't really see how this has anything to do with JavaScript. You might want to provide a more complete example. Right now, the only problem is using `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: Hanky - I am not posting the form. Sadly as its not my code, i dont feel comfortable posting the whole thing online without their permission  (which i cant get at this time). Im getting some of the selected variables from mysql, but i was just attempting to select the user input from the form from the html to keep things simple.

Comment: @Dishonoured are you aware that any html that goes on web is "public" code. you can't hide it. so there is no point hiding it from people trying to help you. just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use double "=" in if statements otherwise you'll just set the variable on the left to the variable on the right, which if successful always returns true.

```
if ($_GET['example']=="sample")
{
$var2= 5;  
}
else
{
$var2= 0; 
}
```

in case you miss the form element here is how you should roughly do:

```
<form method="get" action="">
<select name="example" id="example" >
          <option value="sample">sample</option>
          <option value="sample2">sample2</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this earlier, if i use == it doesnt return true at all. Using only 1 x = returns true. Does the fundamental code work then? Am i missing something else?

Comment: no i mean, the way you use it with single "=" you'll ALWAYS get true. the way i fixed it, you'll get what you intend to.

Comment: also you need to submit a form which encapsulates your selectbox, with a method of "GET"

Comment: Ah, thats really interesting. I didnt realise the 1x= would always validate as true, thats definately part of why im going wrong. Theres ALOT x 1x= in this code, so im starting to wonder if alot of it might not be doing what its meant too...

Comment: @Dishonoured: http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php, http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: Thanks for the links - very insightful. Is there a way to reference directly to the HTML input instead? I tried getElementByID but no cigar.

Comment: this is the value of selected element with js: document.getElementById('example').options[document.getElementById('example').selectedIndex].value